# Finding roots with de Moivre's theorem in trigonometric form

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm stuck on this question: find the roots $z$ of the equation $(1+iz)^7=(1-iz)^7$ in trigonometric form where $(e^{i\theta}-1)/(e^{i\theta}+1)= i\tan(\theta/2)$.

Here are my workings:
$$\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}=1^{1/7}= e^{i2k\pi/7},$$
where $k=0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3$.

From here, do i use the trigonometric form to get: $$\frac{1-iz}{1+iz}=-(e^{i\theta}-1)/(e^{i\theta}+1)= -i\tan(\theta/2)=e^{i2k\pi/7}$$ where $iz=e^{i\theta}$ ?

However, I'm not sure how to continue from here. 
Please help!
Apparently the answer for the question is $z=tan(k\theta/7)$ but i am unable to equate to z even after expansion

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we name $R=e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{7}},$ which never equals $-1$,

$$ \frac{1-iz}{1+iz}=R\Leftrightarrow(1+iz)R=1-iz\Leftrightarrow z(iR+i)=1-R $$

$$\Leftrightarrow z = -i.\frac{1-R}{1+R}=-i\frac{1-e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{7}}}{1+e^{\frac{2ik\pi}{7}}} = i\frac{e^{\frac{ik\pi}{7}}}{e^{\frac{ik\pi}{7}}}\frac{e^{\frac{ik\pi}{7}}-e^{-\frac{ik\pi}{7}}}{e^{\frac{ik\pi}{7}}+e^{-\frac{ik\pi}{7}}}=i\frac{2i\sin \frac{k\pi}{7}}{2\cos \frac{k\pi}{7}}=-\tan{\frac{k\pi}{7}}=\tan\frac{(-k)\pi}{7}$$

which gives you the same set of solutions according to how $k$ is defined.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I didn't realise it could be done this way!

Answer (score 0):

The fraction is the nasty part that you don't know how to deal with. What easy step can you do to get rid of the fraction?

Do that step, then expand things out and look at what you have left. You should be able to solve for $z$ from this point.